# adding a new command to gdb while using cdt eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Good day,
I am writing to you because I tried to follow your instructions [here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/cdt-debug-dsf-gdb-extensibility ] for adding a new command to gdb while using cdt eclipse.
I does not seem to work at all. I put print statements in all of the methods of all the extended classes. Nothing gets printed, which indicates that none of these methods are called. Following is my code. What am I missing?
(i didn't get to the point of actually implementing the new services factory since i there

plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchDelegates">
      <launchDelegate
            delegate="tracerdubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
            id="TracerDubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
            modes="debug, run">
      </launchDelegate>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

> ```
> TracerRunControl:
> ```

```
public class TracerRunControl extends GDBRunControl_7_0 {

    public TracerRunControl(DsfSession session) {
        super(session);
        System.out.println("TracerRunControl");
    }

}
```

//################################################################

```
public class MyTracerLaunchDelegate extends GdbLaunchDelegate implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate2{

    public MyTracerLaunchDelegate() {
        super();
        System.out.println("MyTracerLaunchDelegate::ctr()");
    }


    @Override
    public void launch( ILaunchConfiguration config, String mode, ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor ) throws CoreException {
        System.out.println("MyTracerLaunchDelegate::launch()");      
super.launch(config, mode, launch, monitor);     
    }


    @Override
    protected IDsfDebugServicesFactory newServiceFactory(String version) {
        System.out.println("MyTracerLaunchDelegate");
        return new TracerDebugServicesFactory(version);
    }
}
```

//################################################################

```
public class TracerDebugServicesFactory extends GdbDebugServicesFactory {

    public TracerDebugServicesFactory(String version) {
        super(version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected ICommandControl createCommandControl(DsfSession session, ILaunchConfiguration config) {
        GDBControl_7_0 g = new GDBControl_7_0(session,config);
        System.out.println("TracerDebugServicesFactory::createCommandControl");
        return g;
    }

    @Override
    protected IRunControl createRunControlService(DsfSession session) {
        System.out.println("TracerDebugServicesFactory::createProcessesService");
        return new TracerRunControl(session);  
    }

    @Override
    protected IProcesses createProcessesService(DsfSession session) {
        System.out.println("TracerDebugServicesFactory::createProcessesService");
       return new GDBProcesses_7_0(session);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got the answer from another forum. You must add more info and more extensions:

```
<extension
point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchDelegates">
      <launchDelegate

    delegate="tracerdubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
             delegate="Tracerdubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
            delegateDescription="Your description"
            id="org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.launch.localCLaunch"
            modes="debug"
            name="My GDB Launch Delegate"
            sourceLocatorId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.sourceLocator"
            sourcePathComputerId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.sourcePathComputer"
            type="org.eclipse.cdt.launch.applicationLaunchType">
      </launchDelegate>
   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTypeImages">
            <launchConfigurationTypeImage
            icon="icons/img.gif"
            configTypeID="Tracerdubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
            id="Tracerdubug.TabGroups.launcher.Image">
        </launchConfigurationTypeImage>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups">
        <launchConfigurationTabGroup
            type="Tracerdubug.MyTracerLaunchDelegate"
            class="Tracerdubug.TabGroups.TabGroupTest"
            id="Tracerdubug.TabGroups.TabGroupTest">
        </launchConfigurationTabGroup>
     </extension>
```

and you need a new class = Tracerdubug.TabGroups.TabGroupTest:

```
package Tracerdubug.TabGroups;

import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.internal.ui.launching.CDebuggerTab;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.internal.ui.launching.CMainAttachTab;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.internal.ui.launching.AttachCDebuggerTab;
import org.eclipse.cdt.launch.ui.CArgumentsTab;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.CommonTab;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.EnvironmentTab;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.ILaunchConfigurationDialog;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.ILaunchConfigurationTab;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.sourcelookup.SourceLookupTab;
public class TabGroupTest extends AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup {

    // Create an array of tabs to be displayed in the debug dialog
    public void createTabs(ILaunchConfigurationDialog dialog, String mode) {
        ILaunchConfigurationTab[] tabs = 
            new ILaunchConfigurationTab[] {,
                new CMainAttachTab(),
                new CArgumentsTab(),
                new EnvironmentTab(),
                new SourceLookupTab(),
                new CommonTab(),
            };
        setTabs(tabs);
    }
}
```

You can also create your own tabs, see: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html

My command factory is loaded, I'm now learning how to use an existing service to send the command...